# Access page.php -> Store $_GET variables into cookies -> (how to) Redirect to page.php with no $_get parametres

Tags: php, cookies

what I am trying to do is quite simple but I do now really know how to archive it. 
Ok, so i got site.tld / page.php where few variables which I get helped by $_GET parameter. Somethink just like this.

```
    $var1 = $_GET["var1"];
    $var2= $_GET["var2"];
```

Simple, isn't it? After i get all variables I store them into a small cookie.

```
setcookie(cookievar1,$var1)
setcookie(cookievar2,$var2)
```

Now, after all variables are stored how can i redirect the visitor from page.tld / page.php?var1=something&var2=something2 to page.tld / page.php ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

or:

```
header("location:javascript://history.go(-1)");
```

This may not work with secure pages (HTTPS).

Comment: thank you, but can you explain me how to use it?
I though that using "if" function should solve my problem
I made a simple function like this `code` if ( $CheckifPageReloaded = 0 ) { $CheckifPageReloaded = 1; header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); } `code`
but it doesn't work.